# How does dividing radicals work?

Tags: radicals

Here I have the problem $\dfrac{5\sqrt{24}\cdot 3\sqrt{45}}{\sqrt{6}}$. Not sure how to actually type it out here. How do I actually solve it? The answer says $90\sqrt{5}$ but how?

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{24} = 2\sqrt{6}$, and $\sqrt{45} = 3\sqrt{5}$, from this the answer follows.

Comment: Not really sure where you're getting the answer, can you elaborate a bit aside from just answers, please? Not even sure how you came up with it in the first place. [My account, just forgot to login again].

Comment: The general rule is $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a \cdot \sqrt b$.  So $\sqrt {24}=\sqrt 4 \cdot \sqrt 6 = 2 \sqrt 6$